# Is there any way to get Jacoco code coverage for PowerMockito classes?

Tags: java, junit, jacoco, powermockito

In my project i've used Powermockito.
But Jacoco is not showing the coverage for powermockito classes. 
i've used below jars. 
Could you please help me on it.

```
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.easymock', name: 'easymock', version: '4.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '1.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.20.0-GA'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
    testCompile group: 'org.objenesis', name: 'objenesis', version: '2.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.6.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-support', version: '1.6.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-core', version: '1.6.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.6.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4-common', version: '1.6.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-reflect', version: '1.6.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito-common', version: '1.6.6'


jacoco {
                    toolVersion = '0.7.5.201505241946'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PowerMock` doesn't work with `Jacoco`. I feel the pain.

[Here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/422) is the bug opened.

Some people reported this as working confguration, so you can try:

Working configuration with:

```
jacoco-maven-plugin 0.7.7.201606060606
powermock 1.6.5
```

Comment: I've tried those versions,still same issue.   Is there any alternative Code Coverage Tool to support for PowerMockito ?

Comment: @Praveen there is eCobertura if using Eclipse IDE. But it has it's limitations too. I didn't change the tool for coverage in my project. I removed the Powermockito.

Comment: Have you achieved 100% coverage in your project with OUT PowerMock?

Comment: @Praveen You can do 100% , but you will have problem with mocking `final` classes and `static` methods, since you can't do it with Mockito , but I think you can with `Mockito 2`.

Comment: Mockito 2 means :     'mockito-core', version: '2.1.0'?

Comment: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2